# Multi relations Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have three tables: `groups`, `questions` and `answers`.

`groups` is connected to `questions` in a one to many relationship. Similarly, `questions` has a one to many relationship with `answers`. Editors provide an `answer` to a given question after an admin submits the `groups` and `questions`.

How do I create this in Laravel 5? I think to creating a pivot table for `group_question` and `question_answer` is the right place to start, but I am not sure because I don't know how to later select questions and answers together. Should I instead use `json` and save all questions and answers to one record?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to tackle your problem in Laravel, but the easiest way is probably by using the hasManyThrough relationship. Which can be defined in your Group class something like this:

```
class Group extends Model {

public function answers(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Answer','App\Question');
    }
}
```

just be sure your tables have the following foreign key fields

```
groups
    id - integer
    name - string

questions
    id - integer
    group_id - integer
    text - string

answers
    id - integer
    question_id - integer
    text - string
```

you can read up on more on this in the laravel docs under eloquent relationships.

[See more from Laravel 5's docs on the hasManyThrough relationship here.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#has-many-through)